# Problems with code after updating to Java8

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

Today I dwonloaded Java 8 and NetBeans 8. After installing the JDK and NetBeans I had a look at my project. When I run it my Labels got a bigger size font, the buttons are bigger and my ComboBox don't get its Items by a .txt file. On the old version of Java 7.xx (JavaFx 2.2) there were no problems, my Label and Buttons got normal size and my controller could fill my ComboBox. I changed nothin in my code so it should works....
What could be the problem?I found no answer using google or other commmunities.
Thanks for every help :)

Login-FXML

```
<GridPane   fx:id="loginWindow" fx:controller="homenizer.controller.LoginController" 
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
<padding>
    <Insets top="25" right="25" bottom="10" left="25"/>
</padding> 

<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@/homenizer/view/css/LoginCSS.css"/>
</stylesheets>

<Label  fx:id="welcomeText" text="Willkommen"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" />
<Label  fx:id="username" text="Benutzername"
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
<ComboBox   fx:id="selectUser" editable="true" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" minWidth="180" 
        onAction="#onMenuRequest" />
<Button fx:id="start" text="starten"
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"
    minHeight="25" textAlignment="CENTER" 
    onAction="#onStartRequest" />
<Button fx:id="createUser" text="Benutzer erstellen"
    GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" 
    GridPane.halignment="RIGHT"  
    minHeight="25" textAlignment="CENTER" 
    onAction="#onCreateUserRequest" />   
<Label  fx:id="startStat" 
    GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnSpan="2"  />
```

Login Controlle (snippet)

```
//Benutzer erstellen Button wird gedrückt
    @FXML
    private void onCreateUserRequest(ActionEvent e){
        String username = (String) selectUser.getValue();
        if(selectUser.getItems().contains(username)){
           showStat(Color.RED,"Benutzername schon vorhanden"); // nicht erflogriech
        }else{
            try {
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("src/homenizer/profiles/userlist.txt", "rw");
                File dir = new File("src/homenizer/profiles/"+username);
                dir.mkdir();
                raf.seek(raf.length()); //Ende der Datei suchen
                raf.writeBytes(username+"\r\n"); //Benutzernamen am Ende der speichern und Zeilenumbruch ausgeben
                userID = new UserID(username);
                userID.save();
                selectUser.getItems().add(username);
                showStat(Color.GREEN, "Benutzer erfolgreich angelegt"); //erfolgreich
                raf.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    //ComboBox Inhalt wir ausgegeben
    @FXML
    private void onMenuRequest(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            RandomAccessFile userlist = new RandomAccessFile("src/homenizer/profiles/userlist.txt", "rw");
            while(userlist.getFilePointer() != userlist.length()){
                String username = userlist.readLine();
                if(!(selectUser.getItems().contains(username)))
                    selectUser.getItems().add(username);        //Einträge in ComboBox einfügen
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

For example, the onCreateUserRequest works still fine , but my ComBox shows me no more all created users. With Java 7.xx (JavFx 2.2) it works??

EDIT: Ok, the problem with the big labels and buttons is solved. I set the font to a other, smaller size and no everything looks fine, but the combobox problem still occurs.

Comment: How 'bout posting some code.

Comment: Try to debug your application. Can you read the entries from your file?

Comment: Unrelated note: consider to use try-with-resources to close your files and to use the NIO.2 File API instead of the legacy File class.